# Month number to month names

Tags: mongodb

This may have been answered but I just couldn't find it, what is the suggested way to convert a month number to month name for a value returned in MongoDB.

1. Is there a way in **MongoDB**?
2. Or is it suggested Do the mapping to json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create **ENUM** class supports that **mapping**.

```
public enum Month {
    JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL; //...
}
```

It should not be an issue of the MongoDB. The calls to the database are expensive and you do not want to spend time on simple constants data.