# Using Mongo aggregation how to change numbers to month name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I AM trying this mongo db aggregation i got it  the output but but my requirement is month names display only names .example:   monthname:January ,monthname:February"plase anyone suggest me

```
db.COLLECTION.aggregate([ 
            { $match: {
                CREATE_DATE: {
                    $lte:new Date(),
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new 
                        Date().getDate()-200)
                    )
                }
            } },
            { $group: {
                _id:{ 
                    month: { $month: "$CREATE_DATE" },
                    year: { $year: "$CREATE_DATE" }
                },
                avgofozone:{$avg:"$OZONE"}
            } },
            { $sort:{ "year": -1 } },
            { $project: {
                year: '$_id.year',
                avgofozone: '$avgofozone',
                month: '$_id.month',_id:0
            } }
       ])
    output:
    {
        "_id" : {
            "month" : 4,
            "year" : 2018
        },
        "year" : 2018,
        "avgofozone" : 16.92,
        "month" : 4
    }
    expected output:
    {
        "_id" : {
            "month" : April,
            "year" : 2018
        },
        "year" : 2018,
        "avgofozone" : 16.92,
        "month" : april
    }
```

Comment: Please Show the Document's Data To analyze

Comment: @  Nikhil Savaliya "_id" : ObjectId("5a38d7d5c9790a0cec5f0832"),
    "ID" : "20170223011505924465000000",
    "DISTRICT" : "vskp",
    "STATION" : "APPCB",
    "INDUSTRY" : "2",
    "TAKEN_DT" : ISODate("2017-02-23T00:30:00.000Z"),
    "CARBON_MONOXIDE" : 0.0,
    "OZONE" : 12.69,
    "PM10" : 69.0,
    "PM2DOT5" : 54.0,
    "SULPHUR_DIOXIDE" : 11.2,
    "NITROGEN_DIOXIDE" : 20.11,
    "FLAG1" : "NA",
    "AMMONIA" : 30.92,
    "BENZENE" : 0.58,
    "FLAG2" : "NA",

Comment: "FLAG3" : "NA",
    "FLAG4" : "NA",
    "MODULE_ID" : "100-1",
    "SUBMODULE_ID" : "100-1",
    "SOURCE_OFFICE_ID" : "1000-1",
    "SCREEN_ID" : "100-1",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2017-02-23T01:15:05.924Z"),
    "CREATED_BY" : "1000-1",
    "DB_IP_ADDRESS" : "127.0.0.1",
    "CHECK_CONDITION" : "20170223011505924465000000",
    "RECORD_STATUS" : NumberLong(1),
    "DATA_FROM" : "VUYI"

Comment: Please Update it in Question with proper Formating

Comment: @ Nikhil Savaliya iam geting output:
{
        "_id" : {
            "month" : 4,
            "year" : 2018
        },
        "year" : 2018,
        "avgofozone" : 16.92,
        "month" : 4
    }
but required out put :"month":4 i want  replace "month":april    that's it

Comment: @ Nikhil Savaliya  any possible pleae help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966442/month-number-to-month-names Refer

Comment: @  Nikhil Savaliya  any possible write aggreation ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168924/discussion-between-nikhil-savaliya-and-varun).

Comment: @ Rotem  HOW TO to convert a month number to month name for a value returned in MongoDB. PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 1):

Date data type in MongoDB doesn't support to do your requirement, so the best solution is creating your own collection (Ex: "MyMonth") that stores 12 documents to map month number to month name like that:

```
    db.MyMonth.insert(
         {
             _id: 1,
              "name": "JANUARY"
         }
    );
    db.MyMonth.insert(
         {
             _id: 2,
             "name": "FEBRUARY"
         }
    );
    //...
```

Then, in your aggregate query using $lookup pipeline to join with "MyMonth" to retrieve month name from month number like that:

```
    $lookup:
    {
       from: "MyMonth",
       localField: "month",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "month_data"
    }
    //...
```

Comment: how to add $lookup with above query please suggest me

Comment: @ thoai nguyen  how to add $lookup with above query please suggest me

Comment: You can add two pipelines after your last pipeline like that: ..., {
                $lookup:
                {
                   from: "MyMonth",
                   localField: "month",
                   foreignField: "_id",
                   as: "month_data"
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    year: 1,
                    avgofozone: 1,
                    month: "$month_data.name"
                }
            }...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I approached it by creating a string array with months, and look for the actual value from the array using `$arrayElemAt` operator.

```
// months array
const mL = [
'January',
'February',
'March',
... ]

// $addFields stage
{
    $addFields: {
      month: { $arrayElemAt: [mL, { $getField: 'field name' }] }
    }
}
```